# Why is my 'ontouchstart' event not being triggered on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, events, triggers

This is my code:

```
<div id="a" ontouchstart="touchstart(event);" style="width:100px ; height:100px;background:red;"></div>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function touchstart(event){
            $('#a').css('width','1000px')
        }
</script>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

**updated:***

when i add this code, it can be  triggered:

```
$('#a')[0].addEventListener("touchstart", touchstart, false);
```

So, why is `ontouchstart="touchstart(event);"`  not being triggered?

Comment: Please use better English when asking a question. Also, please explain more in-depth about your question, don't just say "Here's my code, it doesn't work, fix it."

Comment: My English will help you learn Chinese

Comment: Your code runs fine on iphone3 and iphone4 for me?

Answer (score 5):

You need to append the scope to the assignment. Try this

```
<div id="a" ontouchstart="javascript:touchstart(event);" style="width:100px ; height:100px;background:red;"></div>
```