# Speed up loading times while using Phonegap

Tags: android, html, optimization, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to build my apps, and they are working beautifully. My only problem is how long it takes to load pages.

I had to put a splash-page on the first screen so it would be loaded when the user gets to it, but I can't do that for each individual page.

What are some things I can do to speed up load times?

Comment: do you have separate html files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I haven't been able to try this yet, but one tip that I read from one of the co-creators of Phonegap is instead of using onclick when you want an interaction, use ontouchstart. onclick apparently has the potential to wait up to 300ms before running its script, in case the user is double-clicking something. This would get the pages loading sooner if you are using onclick.

Source: http://sintaxi.com/you-half-assed-it

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I'm curious to see if it actually makes a difference.

Comment: The loading is significantly faster, but the button isn't functioning anymore... I guess I'll have to adapt my onclick commands to work with ontouchstart?

Comment: Hm, weird. You may have to change some things around, I'm not entirely sure about how ontouchstart behaves. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9106735/805819) says to say something like "ontouchstart="javascript:functionToCall();"" instead of just the JavaScript to run, so that the scope is declared.

Comment: Update: All pages' loading times are still mind numbingly slow